# Adding clients to groups

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub

I am using signalr in an ASP.net application. I would like my clients to be added to groups when they connect. This way, I can separate messages by groups. I have two questions for the following code

```
public class MyHub : Hub, IDisconnect
{

    private IMyInterface x;
    public MyHub(IMyInterface y)
    {
       x = y;
    }

    public Task Join()
    {
        string group = x.getGroup();
        return Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, group);
    }

    public Task Send(string message)
    {
        string group = x.getGroup();
        return Clients[group].addMessage(message);
    }

    public Task Disconnect()
    {
        string group = x.getGroup();
        return Clients[group].leave(Context.ConnectionId);
    }
}
```

1. Are the Join() and Disconnect() methods called automatically when a client connects and disconnects? If not, where is the best place for me to call it from?
2. I use ninject to resolve my dependencies but it doesnt work in the above code. Are there any extra steps for me to make ninject work with a signalr class?

Anybody?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are the Join() and Disconnect() methods called automatically when a
>   client connects and disconnects? If not, where is the best place for
>   me to call it from?

I'm not aware that Join would be a standard signalr method, however there is [example](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Hubs) in docs for detecting connect, reconnect and disconnect of the client from hub.

```
public class Status : Hub, IDisconnect, IConnected
{
    public Task Disconnect()
    {
        return Clients.leave(Context.ConnectionId, DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }

    public Task Connect()
    {
        return Clients.joined(Context.ConnectionId, DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }

    public Task Reconnect(IEnumerable<string> groups)
    {
        return Clients.rejoined(Context.ConnectionId, DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }
}
```

These are called automatically depending on client behavior and your [configuration](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Configuring-SignalR).